# Can I use JPA CriteriaQueries with Hibernate EntityMode.MAP?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I've been working on using Hibernate to map my metamodel which isn't known at compile-time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061289/hibernate-orm-to-map-to-non-classes)) using `EntityMode.MAP`. I'd like to use the programmatic `Criteria` queries, but as of Hibernate 4 they say that the Hibernate `Criteria` query API is deprecated in favor of JPA. Fine.

But can I use JPA `CriteriaQuery` for non-classes? I don't see a way to specify entities by name instead of by class using "pure" JPA. Is there some Hibernate (non-standard JPA) trickery that enhances the JPA to support `EntityMode.MAP`?

Comment: So by all appearances Hibernate cannot be used as is for EntityMode.MAP and JPA criteria queries. So I'm patching Hibernate. So far I can do single-table queries of concrete classes. All that's left are associations and superclass- and subclass-queries. As soon as its all done I'll push the patch to GitHub.

Comment: See here for changes so far: https://github.com/koehn/hibernate-orm/tree/4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in [HHH-7714](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7714). You must use hibernate versions greater than 4.2.1 (Stable) / 4.3.0.Beta1(Unstable)

All possible credits to ***Koehn***. Thank you for your contribution to the Hibernate Project!